# How can I pass a string from server side coded in VBScript to client side VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, client-side, server-side

I have a string in vbscript on server side that I want to pass to a function in vbscript on the client side. All the examples I have seen were in javascript and were not working for me.
I have a String variable that gets it's value from the server called myprint. I wish to call it like so:

```
<script type="text/VBScript">
Sub Print()
...
str = <%=myprint%>
...
End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far with an example.

Comment: Can you not embed your string into client-side script with `<%= myVar %>`?

Comment: Do not use client side VBScript. Period.

Comment: Show us the code, and we help you.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I realize that you have to wrap "<%= myprint %>" in quotes so it realizes that it is a string. At least that is what I believe as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already realized, you need to enclose the string in quotes. VBScript compilation rules don't change just because you're running it client side. (Client-side VBScript in this day and age is probably not a terribly good idea, btw. One stray Windows Update that gets rid of your old version of IE, and you're dead in the water.)

```
<script type="text/VBScript">
Sub Print()
...
str = "<%=myprint%>"
...
End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: I'm very new to asp and client server interactions and I was just kind of thrown into the water with it at the job I work at. I'm coming from a java and c background so there are still a lot of things that I need to learn about exactly what I am doing.